# How to fix AJAX $.post issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the strangest AJAX bug (or severe case of inexperience) ever. After a $_POST request, only the contents of `div#content` should be updated and nothing else, however, my entire page layout seems to break.

My layout is simple:

`<header>..</header><nav>..</nav>`

`div#left-sidebar` - `div#content` - `div#right-sidebar`

`<footer>..</footer>`

The Javascript used is the following:

```
$("#terms").submit(function(event) {
    if ($("#content #inp_iRead").is(":checked")) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#content img[alt=loading]").show();
        $("#content #terms").hide();
        $.post("reg", {
            ajax_reg: true,
            iRead: 1
        },
        function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data).find("#content");
        }, 
    "html");
        }
    });
```

`#terms` being the form ID and `#inp_iRead` being a checkbox. What I want is to update my `div#content` with the `div#content` returned (in this case it contains only the string `foo :)`).

Below are my expectations (as it appears with JavaScript turned off):
[image: Expectations]

And received result:
[image: Results]

My experience with AJAX is very limited, however, following all the tutorials and what I know so far this code should work.

**My attempt to fix this** was using `filter()` instead of `find()`, which returned the same results. In my opinion, **a possible workaround** could be getting the script to return a JSON object and updating `div#content` with it, however, I am more interested in *fixing* the code that **should** work instead of changing the method used.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: the reason for `if ($("#content #inp_iRead").is(":checked"))` is that otherwise my other live form validation script does not work.

Comment: not sure why you're finding in this line `$("#content").html(data).find("#content");` but anyway, can you show the HTML of `data`? It could be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the `load()` method instead. It's a lot simpler:

```
$('#content').load('reg #content > *', {
    ajax_reg: true,
    iRead: 1
});
```

`reg #content > *` tells `.load()` to load `reg` and replace your element's contents with `#content > *`.

When you pass data to the `load` function, it turns the GET into a POST.

Comment: It doesn't break the layout, however, for some reason the post parameters don't get sent (I'm assuming this because `foo :)` is only echoed if `$_POST['iRead']==1`). Could the issue be that I'm loading the data from the same page?

Comment: @KevinB quote from http://http://api.jquery.com/load/ : `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.`

Comment: @Alorel: Probably not. Can you confirm that the POST parameters are actually being sent to your page?

Comment: Firebug has shown me that post data is indeed sent and I even get the required response string wrapped in the div (checked via view source), however, the div itself does not appear in my browser. I've tried adding `$("#content").show();` to my code with no effect

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. After I've cleared my cache the script began to work. Thanks a lot for your time and help! :)